# Django complicated string representation of a model object (def __str__(self):)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have been using [**str**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#str) to handle human readable names for model objects for awhile now, but recently I have been running into some strange crashes and bugs that seem to be related to this function.

I have two models `SensorAssignment` and `SnComplex`, both have OneToOne relationships to a column on a third model `RadioSn`. `RadioSn` is the master pool of all serial numbers. `SnComplex` is the list of serials assigned to a customer and `SensorAssignment` handles the metadata for a customer's serial assigned to a specific physical location.

It is important to note that this is a legacy db that I inherited. Some relationships are not ideal IMHO.

Below are simplified versions of the models with only relevant columns.

**RadioSn**

```
class RadioSn(models.Model):
    sn = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey('Roles', db_column='role', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'radio_sn'
        ordering = ['sn']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s -- %s' % (self.sn, self.role)
```

**SnComplex**

```
class SnComplex(models.Model):
sn = models.OneToOneField(RadioSn, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sn', primary_key=True)
complex = models.ForeignKey(Complex, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='complex')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'sn_complex'
```

**SensorAssignment**

```
class SensorAssignment(models.Model):
unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='unit')
sn = models.OneToOneField(RadioSn, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sn')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'sensor_assignment'
    ordering = ['sn']

def __str__(self):
    return self.pk
```

Here is where we start to run into my problem. I use `form.ModelForm` to handle the creation and maintenance of `SensorAssignment` objects. Thus for the field `sn` it creates a html `<select>` with choices of `RadioSn` objects which are represented by the str format delineated above (a string composed of the int primary key `sn` and the foreign key `role` [bad naming IMHO]).

This works perfectly (I do limit the querysets to relevant options on the form's initialization on a view, so it isn't `all()` objects in the model.)

[image: Pic of it working]

So I should be able to do the same thing for `SnComplex`, right? After all each model has the same relationship to `RadioSn` on their respective `sn` columns, and the `str` representation of `RadioSn` objects is done on that model.

Nope, this is what I get.

[image: Error]
[image: The line that crashes it]

If I simply represent `RadioSn` objects as `self.sn` instead of concatenating `self.sn` and `self.role` it works on both forms, but if I leave it concatenated is crashes the `SnComplex` form. All `RadioSn` objects have a role value.

Any ideas what is going on? We have a string representation of `RadioSn` model objects crashing the `SnComplex` `ModelForm` on template rendering, but working fine on multiple versions `SensorAssignment` `ModelForm` elsewhere.

**Requested SnComplex form:**

```
class AddSensorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SnComplex
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Full traceback:**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/complex/33/

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['apps.dashboard',
 'rest_framework',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'apps.dashboard.templatetags.custom_filters',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'phonenumber_field',
 'pygal',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\git\si-dash\apps\dashboard\templates\header.html, error at line 0
   Roles matching query does not exist.
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : {% load widget_tweaks %}
   3 : {% load custom_filters %}
   4 : {% csrf_token %}
   5 : 
   6 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   7 : <html lang="en">
   8 : 
   9 : <head>
   10 :     <meta charset="utf-8">


Traceback:

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  158.             rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py" in get_cached_value
  13.             return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]

During handling of the above exception ('role'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\git\si-dash\apps\dashboard\views\complex.py" in complex
  179.     return render(request, 'design/complex.html', passed_data)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\widget_tweaks\templatetags\widget_tweaks.py" in render
  187.         return str(bounded_field)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in <lambda>
  380.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in __str__
  36.         return self.as_widget()

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\widget_tweaks\templatetags\widget_tweaks.py" in as_widget
  31.         html = old_as_widget(widget, attrs, only_initial)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\widget_tweaks\templatetags\widget_tweaks.py" in as_widget
  31.         html = old_as_widget(widget, attrs, only_initial)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\widget_tweaks\templatetags\widget_tweaks.py" in as_widget
  31.         html = old_as_widget(widget, attrs, only_initial)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in as_widget
  118.             **kwargs

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render
  234.         context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in get_context
  677.         context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in get_context
  637.         context['widget']['optgroups'] = self.optgroups(name, context['widget']['value'], attrs)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in optgroups
  585.         for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(self.choices):

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __iter__
  1141.             yield self.choice(obj)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in choice
  1147.         return (self.field.prepare_value(obj), self.field.label_from_instance(obj))

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in label_from_instance
  1213.         return str(obj)

File "C:\git\si-dash\apps\dashboard\models.py" in __str__
  728.         return '%s -- %s' % (self.sn, self.role)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  164.                 rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in get_object
  139.         return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  403.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /complex/33/
Exception Value: Roles matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: let's see your SnComplex Form

Comment: @Lemayzeur added

Comment: so you have the issue when you visit the template where the form actually is... do you have `Roles` entries in your database?

Comment: when you replace this line `return '%s -- %s' % (self.sn, self.role)` with `return self.sn`, did you still get the error? [RadioSn Model]

Comment: @Lemayzeur Every `RadioSn` object has a `Roles` entry. I made a point of saying that in my conclusion. And likewise,`return self.sn` works fine, whereas the current implementation only works on the other forms.

Comment: It might be that `RadioSn` doesn't have an instance for the ForeignKey or the field had something else before you change the field in the db to something else. 1st:I suggest that you ensure that you have an instance for it, and try to save it with another instance (Just for testing) 2nd try to add `null=True,blank=True` to this field `role`, in the db leave it blank and save it (remove `role` from the `__str__`), test the form to see if the error persists, if not, go back to db, add an instance to ForeignKey, re add role to the `__str__` like it was, and test it

Comment: all the tracebacks are important, that's how I can help you debugguging

Comment: The error reads as there is no record in Roles with id 33.  Since you're not cascading when the Roles records are deleted this is possible.

Comment: @Lemayzeur Every `RadioSn` object has an instance of `Roles` in it. I manually checked the db with sql. I'm not sure what you are saying I should test. I have already established that it works when `role` is not part of the `str`

Comment: @HenryM not sure where you are seeing that. The `33` in the url has nothing to do with roles, or assignments. It is the `complex_id` used to tell the view what complex to render the template for.

Comment: @Lemayzeur Added full traceback

Comment: can you just try to change the value of that ForeignKey manually to another one? it's possible that the db has another record if you had had another type of Field there before this ForeignKey. We actually don't know where the issue is, so you have your codes, you should test everything possible to finally find it out

Comment: Ok thanks for the traceback, now edit your codes with the views, I am pretty sure, the bug is there

Comment: @Lemayzeur This is not a form to edit an existing instance. It is a form to create new ones. The `RadioSn` table has thousands of entries.

Comment: @Lemayzeur The entire code for initialization of the form within the view is one line.  `add_sensor_form = AddSensorForm()`. I am not doing anything to it yet, just trying to get it to render.

Comment: @Jon Sorry, you are right it is not Roles id 33 missing.  But it is the Roles associated complex_id 33 which is not in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reviewing the issue you are having and I thought it might be an internal joining error.  I looked at the DB (non django managed) and it appears the radio_sn.role is not set as a foreign key.

Given that it was possible to have a "bad" role associated with a particular sensor.  It looks there was a legacy record of a serial number with a role that didn't exist in the roles table which was the root cause of the join error and the "no role" error you were getting.

I corrected those records and will look into steps into making radio_sn.role a foreign key to the roles table.

Comment: Basically this was an issue of bad legacy db design. I had set up the models to correct some of the relationships, but they couldn't correct for the stray values that role being an int field at the db level allowed.